# Pyspark Cast StructType as ArrayType<StructType>

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df1 with a column col1 that has structure :

```
StructField(recipientResource,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(resourceId,StringType,true),StructField(type,StringType,true))),true),true)
```

and another dataframe df2 with col1 that has structure:

```
StructField(recipientResource,StructType(List(StructField(resourceId,StringType,true),StructField(type,StringType,true))),true)
```

Inorder to union df1.union(df2), I was trying to cast the column in df2 to convert it from StructType to ArrayType(StructType), however nothing which I tried has worked out.

Can anyone suggest how to go about the same. 
I'm new to pyspark, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `array<struct<...>>` and `struct<...>` are two completely different objects - you cannot cast one into another. You could add wrapping `array` if that's what you mean, like `select(array(struct_column))`.

Comment: An [mcve] with a small sample of your dataframes and the desired output would be helpful. See more on [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using array() function:

Input:

df1 (with ArrayType(StructType()) column):

[image]

df2 (with StructType() column):

[image]

Code:

```
df2=(df2
     .withColumn('recipientResource',array(col('recipientResource'))) #convert StructType() column to ArrayType(StructType()) column
    )
```

Output:

Modified df2:

[image]

df3 (output after union of df1 and df2):

[image]